# Destroying a helicopter with a throwing knife -- How hard?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

I saw a youtube video some time ago of a guy throwing a throwing knife straight up, getting 5 hit markers and then a kill. In his video he watched the throwing knife and it apparently bounced on the helicopter 5 times then went down a killed a guy.

I know it's possible now to kill someone by throwing a throwing knife straight up(though very improbable) but is it possible to destroy a helicopter with a throwing knife?

How much damage does a throwing knife do to a helicopter in comparison to say a locked on SMAW missle?

(note, I've been able to hit a helicopter with a throwing knife before and got 3 hit markers, so I know it's possible to hit them and not faked)

Comment: From the perspective of a real soldier, this is just hilarious.

Answer (score 7):

12 Throwing knife hits will destroy an attack helicopter. Attack helicopters have 1500 health and throwing knives in MW3 multiplayer do 135 damage. 1500/135= ~11.1 but you will need 12 throwing knives to actually kill it.

Comment: that is seriously dumb